# Combining results with DateDiff included

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a list of places where people have been discharged and I need to stratify them by age.  The query that I have currently below works, but it lists every discharge type count, by every age.   [image]

You can see how for age 0-1-2-3 there are all separate counts of discharge type based on what age.  How can I make it so that it's only the `dischargeType` and the counts that are listed (as long as they are 18 and under)

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(yyyy, tblVisits.dob, tblVisits.admitdate) AS Age, tblDischarge.dischargeType, COUNT(tblDischarge.dischargeType) AS COUNTS
FROM tblVisits INNER JOIN
               tblDischarge ON tblVisitsDischargeStatus = tblDischarge.dis_statID
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(yyyy,tblVisits.dob, tblVisits.Admitdate), tblDischarge.dischargeType
HAVING (DATEDIFF(yyyy,tblVisits.DOB, tblVisits.AdmitDate) <=18)
```

Comment: My flesh crawls with the concept of a column called "dischargeType" in a medical database...

Comment: Not a medical database :) research.

Comment: `I need to stratify them by age` and `can I make it so that it's only the dischargeType and the counts that are listed` seem to be contradictory.  Do you just one one row per dischargeType, counting all those aged under 18?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want people aged under 18, but only one row per discharge-type...

```
SELECT
  tblDischarge.dischargeType,
  COUNT(tblDischarge.dischargeType) AS COUNTS
FROM
  tblVisits
INNER JOIN
  tblDischarge
    ON tblVisitsDischargeStatus = tblDischarge.dis_statID
WHERE
  (DATEDIFF(yyyy,tblVisits.DOB, tblVisits.AdmitDate) <=18) 
GROUP BY
  tblDischarge.dischargeType
```

If you want to group the ages into strata...

```
SELECT
  tblDischarge.dischargeType,
  CASE DATEDIFF(yyyy,tblVisits.DOB, tblVisits.AdmitDate)
     WHEN <=  3 THEN '0..3'
     WHEN <=  8 THEN '4..8'
     WHEN <= 12 THEN '9..12'
                ELSE '13..18'
  END                               AS ageBand,
  COUNT(tblDischarge.dischargeType) AS COUNTS
FROM
  tblVisits
INNER JOIN
  tblDischarge
    ON tblVisitsDischargeStatus = tblDischarge.dis_statID
WHERE
  (DATEDIFF(yyyy,tblVisits.DOB, tblVisits.AdmitDate) <=18)
GROUP BY
  tblDischarge.dischargeType,
  CASE DATEDIFF(yyyy,tblVisits.DOB, tblVisits.AdmitDate)
     WHEN <=  3 THEN '0..3'
     WHEN <=  8 THEN '4..8'
     WHEN <= 12 THEN '9..12'
                ELSE '13..18'
  END
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of your problem, but if you just want to count by `dischargeType`, for all people under 18, the code follows:

```
SELECT dis.dischargeType, COUNT(dis.dischargeType) AS COUNTS
FROM tblDischarge dis
JOIN tblVisits    vst ON vst.DischargeStatus = dis.dis_statID
WHERE (DATEDIFF(yyyy,vst.DOB, vst.AdmitDate) <= 18)
GROUP BY dis.dischargeType;
```

Or you can use sub-query, like:

```
SELECT dischargeType, COUNT(dischargeType) AS COUNTS
FROM tblDischarge
WHERE dis_statID IN (
    SELECT vst.DischargeStatus
    FROM tblVisits vst
    WHERE (DATEDIFF(yyyy, vst.DOB, vst.AdmitDate) <= 18)
)
GROUP BY dis.dischargeType;
```

Comment: Neither query will run.  In TSQL you *must* `GROUP BY dischargeType`.

Comment: Sure, @Dems, guess I overlooked the basics. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the AGE in the selection and in the Group by part:

```
SELECT tblDischarge.dischargeType, COUNT(tblDischarge.dischargeType) AS COUNTS
FROM tblVisits INNER JOIN
               tblDischarge ON tblVisitsDischargeStatus = tblDischarge.dis_statID
GROUP BY tblDischarge.dischargeType
HAVING (DATEDIFF(yyyy,tblVisits.DOB, tblVisits.AdmitDate) <=18)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the calculation for age from the `SELECT` and the `GROUP BY`, and change the `HAVING` to a `WHERE`:

```
SELECT tblDischarge.dischargeType,
        COUNT(tblDischarge.dischargeType) as COUNTS
FROM tblVisits 
INNER JOIN tblDischarge
  ON tblVisitsDischargeStatus = tblDischarge.dis_statID
WHERE (DATEDIFF(yyyy,tblVisits.DOB, tblVisits.AdmitDate) <=18) 
GROUP BY tblDischarge.dischargeType
```